# Distribution of the target given all data and respective targets and new input - Bishops' PRML book

Tags: probability-theory, machine-learning, bayesian

In 1.2.6 he gives this equation (1.68):

$$p(t|x,\mathbb{x},\mathbb{t}) = \int p(t|x,\mathbb{w})p(\mathbb{w}|\mathbb{x},\mathbb{t}) d\mathbb{w} \tag{1.68}$$

And this is just a distribution over $t$ given the new data point $x$ and all the data $\mathbb{x}$ and respective targets $\mathbb{t}$. But the author does not give a motivation of why the LHS is equal to the RHS. And I am interested in precisely knowing how to write out the expression on the RHS, if I were given the expression on the LHS.

To give some more details:
$$p(t|x,\mathbb{w})= \mathcal{N}(t|y(x,\mathbb{w}),\beta^{-1}) \tag{1.60}$$
and 
$$p(\mathbb{w}|\mathbb{x},\mathbb{t},\alpha,\beta) \propto p(\mathbb{t}|\mathbb{x},\mathbb{w},\beta)p(\mathbb{w}|\alpha)$$
i.e. a posterior distribution is proportional to likelihood times prior.
So we would obtain the $p(\mathbb{w}|\mathbb{x},\mathbb{t})$ term in the integral by normalizing the distribution in (1.60).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is one of predicting a new target at a given, non-random, input point $x$ where $\mathbb{w}$ is distributed under the posterior having observed the targets $\mathbb{t}$ at the input points $\mathbb{x}$, therefore the posterior only has a dependence on those input points to which there also corresponds some observed target, that is
$$
p(\mathbb{w}|x,\mathbb{x},\mathbb{t})=p(\mathbb{w}|\mathbb{x},\mathbb{t})
$$
so then by marginalising over $\mathbb{w}$ you have
$$
\begin{align*}
p(t|x,\mathbb{x},\mathbb{t}) &= \int p(t, \mathbb{w} | x, \mathbb{x}, \mathbb{t} ) d\mathbb{w}  \\
&= \int  p(t | \mathbb{w}, x, \mathbb{x}, \mathbb{t} ) p(\mathbb{w} | x, \mathbb{x}, \mathbb{t}) d\mathbb{w} \\
&= \int p(t|\mathbb{w},x,\mathbb{x},\mathbb{t})p(\mathbb{w}|\mathbb{x},\mathbb{t})d\mathbb{w}
\end{align*}
$$
Now it follows from $t|x,\mathbb{w} \sim \mathcal{N}\left(y(x,\mathbb{w}), \beta^{-1} \right)$ that the distribution of the target $t$ at a new point $x$ depends only on that point and the parameters $\mathbb{w}$, as well as the parameter $\beta$ but that is being suppressed here for keeping the notation compact, and therefore
$$
p(t|\mathbb{w},x,\mathbb{x},\mathbb{t})= p(t|\mathbb{w},x),
$$
which gives the quoted result.

In summary one goes from the fully specified conditionals to their more compact representations by considering information that becomes redundant due to any conditional independence properties of the model. So for example conditional on the specific parameters $\mathbb{w}$ of the model, knowing the input points $\mathbb{x}$ and $\mathbb{t}$ from which the posterior information regarding these parameters arose gives us no new information regarding the distribution of $t$ at a new point $x$ because conditional on their respective input points, and the model parameters, each target is independent
$$
\begin{align*}
p(t, \mathbb{t}|x,\mathbb{x},\mathbb{w} ) &= \mathcal{N}(t|y(x,\mathbb{w}),\beta^{-1})\prod_{i \; : \; x_i \in \mathbb{x} }\mathcal{N}\left(t_i | y(x_i, \mathbb{w}), \beta^{-1} \right) \\
&= p(t|x,\mathbb{w})p(\mathbb{t}|\mathbb{x},\mathbb{w}).
\end{align*}
$$

Comment: You have a very good knowledge of ML, did you do a course/ a PhD on this?

Comment: thanks for this example at the bottom. I liked it, made things clearer too!

Comment: No problem, glad I was able to help, these are important questions because it is very important to keep track of how these models get factorised and to get as comfortable with that process as possible especially as the models get more complicated. Also big fan of Bishop's book

Comment: whenever I do maths and stumble upon something I do not understand I will get stuck on it for as long as it takes to fully understand it. That is why my progress is quite slow at times. I will try to solve this integral tomorrow to arrive at the result that they have in the book. If I cannot, there will be another question tomorrow:)