# Probability of target given new input and all data along with corresponding targets - Bishop's PRML book

Tags: probability, probability-theory, machine-learning

In relation to the question I have posted [earlier](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2448704/distribution-of-the-target-given-all-data-and-respective-targets-and-new-input).

I tried to solve the integral:
$$p(t|x,\mathbf{x},\mathbf{t}) = \int p(t|x,\mathbf{w})p(\mathbf{w}|\mathbf{x},\mathbf{t}) d\mathbf{w} \tag{1.68}$$ to show that:
$$p(t|x,\mathbf{x},\mathbf{t}) = \mathcal{N}(t|m(x),s^2(x)) \tag{1.69}$$
where the mean and variance are:
$$m(x) = \beta \phi(x)^T \mathbf{S}\sum_{n=1}^N \phi(x_n)t_n \tag{1.70}$$ 
$$s^2(x) = \beta^{-1}+\phi(x)^T\mathbf{S}\phi(x) \tag{1.71}$$
And matrix $\mathbf{S}$ is given by:
$$\mathbf{S}^{-1} = \alpha \mathbf{I} + \beta\sum_{n=1}^N \phi(x_n)\phi(x_n)^T \tag{1.72}$$
and vector $\phi(x)$ is defined with elements: $\phi_i(x)=x^i$ for $i=0,...,M$.

What I am really interested in is whether I have made any mistakes in the below, because I believe once you reach the last line in the below it just becomes a matter of applying the rule of multiplication of multivariate Gaussians (and it is quite tedious)?

My workings:
$$p(t|x,\mathbf{x},\mathbf{t}) = \int p(t|x,\mathbf{w})p(\mathbf{w}|\mathbf{x},\mathbf{t}) d\mathbf{w} \\
= \int \frac{\mathcal{N}(t|y(x,\mathbf{w},\beta^{-1})) \prod_{i: x_i \in \mathbf{x}} \mathcal{N}(t_i|y(x_i,\mathbf{w},\beta^{-1}) p(\mathbf{w}|\alpha)}{\int p(\mathbf{t}|\mathbf{x},\mathbf{w},\beta) p(\mathbf{w}|\alpha) d\mathbf{w}} d\mathbf{w} $$
Let $\tilde{t} = [t,t_1,t_2,..,t_M]^T$ and $\tilde{x} = [x,x_1,...,x_M]^T$, also note that $\int p(\mathbf{t}|\mathbf{x},\mathbf{w},\beta) p(\mathbf{w}|\alpha) d\mathbf{w} =c \in \mathbb{R}$, therefore:
$$= c \int \prod_{i: x_i \in \tilde{x}} \mathcal{N} (t_i|y(x_i,\mathbf{w}),\beta^{-1})p(\mathbf{w}|\alpha) d\mathbf{w} \tag{last line}$$
where $p(\mathbf{w}|\alpha)=\left( \frac{\alpha}{2\pi} \right)^{(M+1)/2} \exp \Big\{ -\frac{\alpha}{2} || w ||^2 \Big\}$

Comment: That all looks good to me - you could if you wanted to use the same logic that $p(\mathbf{w} | \mathbf{x}, \mathbf{t} ) \propto p(\mathbf{t}|\mathbf{x},\mathbf{w}) p(\mathbf{w})$ to solve for the posterior distribution first and then perform the integral $(1.68)$, but the answer should be exactly the same as your last line equation.

Comment: Thanks! I am implementing a toy Python problem now to test my knowledge of this equation. Will put it up on my blog afterwards.

Comment: @Nadiels hmm not quite getting a smooth curve like he has... At each step I am adding observed inputs x to the vector_x and calculating the probability of the target for the new_x using that information iteratively, and thus I should get a smooth m(x) like he has, isn't that right?

Comment: Not sure exactly what you mean? If you are forming the predictive distribution on increasing subsets of data then yeah it should definitely be smooth, roughly the mean should be an interpolating polynomial that passes near the observed targets with width controlled by $\beta$.

Comment: I have generated dummy sinusoidal data with some noise, that is my data vector $\mathbf{x}$, I then iteratively add more data and compute the $p(t|x,\mathbf{x},\mathbf{t})$ and I am getting pretty much a flat line. And I am quite sure that my functions are implemented correctly. Hmm..

Comment: I think the reason for why I am getting a weird line for the means is because there is a typo in Bishops book in equation 1.72